# context.executeQueryAsync not working in Master Page

Tags: javascript, master-page, custom-masterpage, sp.sod

I have some JSOM code in my master page(seattle.master). The code runs until load() method on the context object but executeQueryAsync is not executing.

```
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){

                        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();   
                        var web = context.get_web();            
                        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(list_title);
                        context.load(list);
                        context.executeQueryAsync(function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        },
                          function(data,args){
                            console.log(args);
                        });
},'sp.js');
```

Neither of the log statements in the success nor the error function is getting printed.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you specifying the list's title for `getByTitle` somewhere - is it just hidden in this question?

Comment: Yes, it is not specified in this question but it holds a value for the list title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your code like below:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();   
    var web = context.get_web();            
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(list_title);
    context.load(list);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    },
      function(data,args){
        console.log(args);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`executeQueryAsync` requires both *succeededCallback* and *failedCallback* parameters per [SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync method (sp.js)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907.aspx). I think you are missing the *failedCallback*.

Comment: I do have two callbacks in my code. two callback functions inside executeQueryAsync

context.executeQueryAsync(function(data){      
                        console.log(data);
                        },
                          function(data,args){               
                            console.log(args);
                        });

Comment: @YashwanthRao right! Pardon my sloppiness. I think this case might fall under the definition of *asynchronous* and the requirements it sets. There are a couple of useful sources to explain it further over here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53484/how-to-return-a-value-using-context-executequeryasync & http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108819/difference-in-clientcontext-load-and-clientcontext-executequeryasync-in-java